# How to correctly set limits ports?

Tags: ubuntu, firewall, ddos, ufw, ubuntu-22.04

So im currently working on setting a simpel server up with a game server using port 30110 and 30120, but i clearly getting dossed like crazy, how is the best way to protect against this, like i have used the following tables.

```
Apache Full           ALLOW       Anywhere
3389/tcp              DENY        Anywhere
OpenSSH               LIMIT       Anywhere
30110                 ALLOW       Anywhere
30120                 ALLOW       Anywhere
4489/tcp              LIMIT       Anywhere
```

But for what i can understand here is that its open no matter what, not waiting for a service or anything... what is the best approach to open them so users can connect but no DDOS/brute attacks cant happen?

Im using Ubuntu 22.04

Thanks in advace!

Answer (score 0):

fail2ban perhaps?

Some hardening tips here would also be useful:

https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-security.html

Comment: Forgot about fail to ban... but hey thanks, now i simply have to figure out some way of better filtering the incoming requests as right now i have 66mb/s ddos attacking incoming that my host filters but someone still get thru sadly.